# Wait for big files to open in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, loops, csv

I've been trying to loop over a bunch of big .csv files in VBA. Each of them is approximately 50MB. At every iteration I open a new CSV to manipulate data but when the .csv is opening there is a downloading message saying that the file is opening and the progress bar always gets stuck at some point while the VBA is waiting for it to finish.

Actually the .csv is opened because if I click "cancel" on the progress bar the code continues running well but I have to do a manual action at every iteration.

My guess is that VBA goes to the next step while the file is not opened or something like that so maybe if I do a Sleep or something like that it could work but what I tried did not work for now. (I already tried Application.EnableEvents = False). Here is my code:

```
Sub GetOptions()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

Set Dates = Sheets("Dates")
Set Res = Sheets("Options")

Dim dateToday As Date

ETF = "SPY"
nrows = Dates.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row


For i = 708 To nrows

    If Dates.Cells(i, 2).Value = "B" Then
        dateToday = Dates.Cells(i, 1).Value
        dateYear = Year(dateToday)
        stringOpening = "P:\Options Database\CSV\" & dateYear & "\bb_" & dateYear & "_" & GetMonth(dateToday) & "\bb_options_" & Format(dateToday, "yyyymmdd") & ".csv"
        Workbooks.Open stringOpening, UpdateLinks:=0, ReadOnly:=True
        Set Options = Workbooks("bb_options_" & Format(dateToday, "yyyymmdd")).Sheets(1)

        Do things...

        Workbooks("bb_options_" & Format(dateToday, "yyyymmdd")).Close SaveChanges:=False
    End If
Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: I suggest that you test and finalize your code with small files first. Get your code to run correctly on a set of small (or medium) files and get comfortable with it, and only then move to the big files, it will be easier to assess the problem.

Comment: Thx but I already tried it on smaller files and it works correctly, it only get stucks when it comes to big files (>30-40MB)

Comment: What is your P drive mapped to?  A network folder, or something else?

Answer (score 2):

A trick would be :

1. to open them as Read/Write files,
2. wait for the Write status which indicates that it is fully opened
3. set back the file to Read Only

This code loops until the file goes into a Write status :

```
Sub myWaitForFileOpen()
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Open("C:\File.xls")

Do Until wb.ReadOnly = False
    wb.Close
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
    Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Open("C:\File.xls")
Loop
'Then the code that needs that Workbook open here!
'Or Call That other macro here!
End Sub
```

Here is your full code, that will open the CSV in Read/Write until it is fully loaded and then put it back to read only :

```
Sub GetOptions()
Dim wB As Workbook

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

Set Dates = Sheets("Dates")
Set Res = Sheets("Options")

Dim dateToday As Date

ETF = "SPY"
nrows = Dates.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row


For i = 708 To nrows
    If Dates.Cells(i, 2).Value = "B" Then
        dateToday = Dates.Cells(i, 1).Value
        dateYear = Year(dateToday)
        stringOpening = "P:\Options Database\CSV\" & dateYear & "\bb_" & dateYear & "_" & GetMonth(dateToday) & "\bb_options_" & Format(dateToday, "yyyymmdd") & ".csv"

        Set wB = Workbooks.Open(stringOpening, UpdateLinks:=0, ReadOnly:=False)

        Do Until wB.ReadOnly = False
            wB.Close

            Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")

            Set wB = Application.Workbooks.Open("C:\My Files\AAA.xls")
        Loop
        wB.ReadOnly = True
        Set Options = wB.Sheets(1)


        Do
            'things...
        Loop

        wB.Close SaveChanges:=False
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm confused how this works? I appears to me that it tries to open the file, which opens as readonly until its fully open when it gets changed over to readwrite. I think that makes sense, but the answer seems if it is readonly, then close it, wait a second, and try opening it again. How does this make it open a large file? Seems like it would just continually open and close the file over and over.

Comment: After testing, this is indeed what I get... perhaps something changed since this was posted in 2015?

Comment: Oh, my file I was opening was readonly to begin with... changed that and it works... still don't understand why, but it does.

Comment: @JasonBrady : Honestly... I don't remember why I did that when I read it, the `close` seems suspicious to me too !^^ I still agree with the general idea, but that part is now a mystery to me !

Answer (score 1):

Here is a similar approach that worked well for me. The idea is that at the start of a sub, you check if the workbook is already loaded. If not, the sub is closed (`Exit Sub`) and I wait a second before running the same function again.

**Important**: You can't use `Application.Wait`, otherwise Excel won't load the workbook at all. Here you could get into an endless loop. But with `Application.OnTime` it should work.

Here is a code example:

```
Private Sub run_after_wb_loaded()
    ' delay start of procedure until workbook is loaded
    If ActiveWorkbook Is Nothing Then
        Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), Procedure:="run_after_wb_loaded"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' do stuff
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to open the file and use it immediately Excel might
give an error because Excel activates file opening process and goes to execute next statement. A quick and dirty workaround for not very long files is to introduce an extra code that is not related to a file thus keeping Excel busy while file is going through the opening process.